# How to use Polymer <app-route> for routing two components that doesn't share its UI

Tags: routes, polymer, progressive-web-apps

**The problem:**

1. I created an app based on the [Polymer shop app](https://github.com/Polymer/shop).
2. It has no session management, so I implemented it with passport and express.
3. The Polymer app, has no sign-in/sign-up views(obviously). So I have to create them (combined both into one).
4. But it'd be weird (and bad) if I added the sign-in/sign-up view within the `<app-route>` system provided by the shop app.
5. So I created another web component that takes care of the sign-in/sign-up stuff, including interactions with the express server.

**The goal is to:**

6. Create a web component which will live above both sign-in/sign-up and really-my-app components.
7. This root component, would have its own `<app-route>` managing just the visibility of those views. I DO NOT NEED nor WANT a sidebar (or a navbar) that allows the user to go to another view.
8. The behavior I expect, is to show the login view, when visiting /login, and to show the app view when visiting /app.
9. But sadly, I can't find any example of any app demonstrating this very basic (I suspect) behavior. All of them do it with fancy sidebars or navbars or some kind of visual control based on the polymer starter kit, or shop app.

**So:**

10. Can anyone, please, help me to solve this?
11. Also, I'm assuming that nesting the `<app-route>` from the polymer app, in the `<app-route>` from the root component wont cause troubles. Is this assumption right?

Tank you so much for helping me out. **You are awesome.**

Comment: Try to check this [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/routing) about Routing with <app-route>, you will find here all the possible way on using the <app-route>. For more information, you can also check this [thread](https://auth0.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-polymer-and-web-components/).

Comment: First link seems to be what I'm looking for. Maybe not as in a direct example, but in an abstract way to get where I wan to. Second link uses the starter kit, which I want to avoid. But the firs will do, apparently. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can check this app made by Vaadin, Demo: https://demo.vaadin.com/expense-manager/ and Source: https://github.com/vaadin/expense-manager-demo.